# Use of for loops to create shapes with asterisks

Tags: c++

I'm studying for a programming test and one of the questions will involve looking at code which prints a shape using asterisks. The code below is similar to what will be on the test, although, the test question will output a different shape. I'm at somewhat of a loss as to how this code works. I understand the concept of a for loop, but not the role each of these for loops plays in the program. Below, is the code and it's output.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int m, n;
  for (m = 0; m<10; m++)
    {
      for (n = 0; n<m; n++) cout << " ";
      for (n = 0; n<(19-2*m); n++) cout << "*";
      for (n = 0; n<m; n++) cout << " ";
      cout << endl;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
*******************
 *****************
  ***************
   *************
    ***********
     *********
      *******
       *****
        ***
         *
```

Comment: One outer loop for the lines, one inner loop for the leading spaces, one inner loop for the asterisks. The inner loop for the trailing spaces is not needed. The amount of loops, and their conditions will of course be different depending on the "shape" you want to print.

Comment: User pencil and paper to trace the execution and the output of the program one statement at a time. Notice how the output looks like after each loop. Repeat.

Comment: Welcome to SO! One way to approach other's code is asking yourself "how would I implement it?" You would iterate down the lines while within each line output the symbols according to the shape wouldn't you? (Of course idiomatically using ++m and ++n, not sloppily using the postfix ops, and caring for proper code layout, of course).

Comment: This is great advice I will be sure to do so on my exam, thank you!

Comment: @Evan1376 a good advice is also to accept an answer you like from the given ones.

Comment: I already attempted to do so, it required me to wait 7 minutes.

Comment: That's logical @Evan1376, in order to give people some time to answer, so that the guy asked accepts the best answer and not just the first to come. Good luck with your test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (m = 0; m<10; m++)                      // this one loops over the rows of the shape
{
  for (n = 0; n<m; n++) cout << " ";        // to leave spaces before the shape
  for (n = 0; n<(19-2*m); n++) cout << "*"; // to fill the shape with *
  for (n = 0; n<m; n++) cout << " ";        // to leave spaces after the shape
  cout << endl;                             // change line
}
```

As the guys stated, the last loop is not required to get this particular shape, but since this is for your test study, make sure to understand that too, since in the test, any similar shape could pop-up, which may require all the loops (otherwise, why the teacher put it there?.

Comment: The third for loop to put spaces after printing *s is redundant.

Comment: @Raul in *this particular* shape yes. In many other shapes, no.

Comment: The other examples I was given were hollow triangles, boxes, possibly a heart shape (which I haven't seen code for anywhere i've looked)

Comment: @Evan1376 focus on this one and you will be fine if you understand it.

Comment: @gsamaras, I tried this with many shapes..it is working for all the shapes. Still, it would be great if you can help identify any such shape that it doesn't work with.

Comment: @Raul, one like this shape with the two legs.

Comment: @gsamaras with respect to your comments to the OP in the main thread, please see [Dealing with an answer that wasn't accepted (maybe because a user is a newbie in SO)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251288/1708801)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (m = 0; m<10; m++) //This is the main loop to print the 10 rows
{
  for (n = 0; n<m; n++) cout << " "; //This loops provide all the spaces before the first element of each row
  for (n = 0; n<(19-2*m); n++) cout << "*"; //prints the *s
  for (n = 0; n<m; n++) cout << " "; //Not required here....you can get the same output without this.
  cout << endl;
}
```